# Not showing model defaults in template

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, handlebars.js

I have the following backbone application:

On the index.html:

```
<div class='content'></div>

<div class='container'>
   <script type="type="text/x-handlebars-template"" id="product-template">
       <h2>Products</h2>

       <h3>{{ this.title }}</h3>
   </script>
</div>
```

and the main.js:

```
$(function() {

var Product = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        title: "Title",
        user_id: 0,
        description: "Description"
    }
});

var ProductView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: ".content",
    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        var source = $('#product-template').html();
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
        var html = template(Product.model);
        this.$el.html(html);
    }
});

var productView = new ProductView();

});
```

It's showing the "Products" heading, so the template is rendering but it's not showing the `{{this.title }}`. Unfortunately, there isn't any errors showing up in the console, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
var ProductView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: ".content",
    model: new Product,
    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        var source = $('#product-template').html();
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
        var html = template(this.model.toJSON());
        this.$el.html(html);
    }
});
```

to print it

```
{{ title }}
```